# svcutil generated unneccesary wrapper classes

Tags: wsdl, svcutil.exe

I am working on a project that uses the contract first approach. I was given a `WSDL` and three `xsd's`. When I use `svcutil` it generates a wrapper around the response class like so:

```
public partial class getDataByIdResponse1 {

    public getDataByIdResponse getDataByIdResponse;

    public getDataByIdResponse1() {
    }

    public getDataByIdResponse1(getDataByIdResponse getDataByIdResponse) {
        this.getDataByIdResponse = getDataByIdResponse;
    }
}
```

The `getDataByIdResponse` is wrapped inside a `getDataByIdResponse1` object. This is done by `svcutil` and I have no idea why. The `getDataByIdResponse1` object does not exist in the `WSDL`:

```
<wsdl:message name="getDataById">
    <wsdl:part name="response" element="tns:getDataByIdResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

<xs:element name="getDataByIdResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="data" type="sbc:DataType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Why is the type `getDataByIdResponse` wrapped in `getDataByIdResponse1`? Is there a switch for `svcutil` I should have used?

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat as you but I don't just want to live with it.  I want to generate clean (unwrapped) contracts.  If the wsdl and xsd's were given to you then there are some rules that your schema and wsdl need to follow in order for svc util to generate unwrapped code.  These links helped me understand the issue a little better

http://pzf.fremantle.org/2007/05/handlign.html

http://mharbauer.wordpress.com/2007/10/19/wcf-datacontract-serializer-and-documentwrapped/

For now my schema and wsdl are small enough that I can tweak them to adhere to this rules.
However, like Ron, I've also been in situations where the easiest thing is just to live with it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation (contract-first) and svcutil is generating this same kind of code for me but I just closed my eyes took a deep breath and accepted it :-)

Just use the types without the numeric postfix and it just works.

Comment: "Just use the types without the numeric postfix and it just works.", I don't think the C# code will compile that way. types without the numeric postfix are totally different names for the compilers.